# Support content effect (highlight, lift and hover) for mouse and trackpad on iPadOS 13.4

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I have implemented UIButton as custom renderer in Xamarin.Forms project.  Is there a sample project to demonstrate how to implement content effects like highlight using UIPointerInteraction class?  Specifically, is there an equivalent for this sample code in Xamarin? [Integrating Pointer Interactions into Your iPad App](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/pointer_interactions/integrating_pointer_interactions_into_your_ipad_app)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing some research and I did not find a sample project about `UIPointerInteraction`.

While I think you can use it in the latest `Xamarin.iOS 13.6.0` as those classes has been added to Xamarin.iOS in this version:

[new-type-uikituipointerregion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/release-notes/api-changes/ios-13-14-1-13-16-0#new-type-uikituipointerregion)

[new-type-uikituipointerregionrequest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/release-notes/api-changes/ios-13-14-1-13-16-0#new-type-uikituipointerregionrequest)

I wrote a simple example about how to initialize `UIPointerInteraction` :

```
public override void ViewDidLoad()
{

    base.ViewDidLoad();

    // Perform any additional setup after loading the view
    pointerDelegate myDelegate = new pointerDelegate(); 

    UIPointerInteraction interPointer = new UIPointerInteraction(myDelegate);
}



public class pointerDelegate : UIPointerInteractionDelegate {

    public override void WillEnterRegion(UIPointerInteraction interaction, UIPointerRegion region, IUIPointerInteractionAnimating animator)
    {
        base.WillEnterRegion(interaction, region, animator);
    }

    public override void WillExitRegion(UIPointerInteraction interaction, UIPointerRegion region, IUIPointerInteractionAnimating animator)
    {
        base.WillExitRegion(interaction, region, animator);
    }
}
```

Feel free to ask me if you have any difficulty when transferring swift/OC code from native iOS to C# in Xamarin.iOS.

Comment: The code detects the mouse entering and exiting the element.  However, how do I change the mouse default pointer (circle) to content highlight effect (which highlights the entire UIButton) upon entering and returns to default circle pointer upon exiting?

Comment: Maybe use [this method](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipointerinteractiondelegate/3538996-pointerinteraction?language=objc) may work? You can override it in the pointerDelegate too.

Comment: Thanks Jack. It works. The circle-shaped pointer disappears and the image button is highlighted when mouse over. Thanks.